# rails sqlserver views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord, view

how is it possible to work from rails and use sqlserver views?

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

doesn't generate schema for views

I've used `rails_sql_views` gem but something is buggy. probably because of sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it possible, and sometimes convenient. I'm using views to fetch some data from legacy database. But views are read-only.

Comment: class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'view_name'
end